# Powershell: accessing remote registry via WMI

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I have a script that simply connects to the registry of a remote computer via WMI and Powershell:

```
$Server = server1
$HKLM = [UInt32] "0x80000002"
$WMI_Reg = [WMIClass] "\\server1\root\default:StdRegProv"
```

For the majority of our 300 servers this is fine and I can make subsequent queries on the registry. However, for a select few, I get this error:

> Cannot convert value "\server1\root\default:stdregprov" to type
>   "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "not found"

These are all 2008 R2 servers. Originally, there were issues with invalid WMI providers and I had to recompile cimWin32.mof prior to this error.

Any ideas on what I can do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These errors are usually caused by missing WMI classes. The solution for this kind of error usually involves couple of steps.

The solutions could be found under this link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/08/11/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class/

Important: as per Microsoft, please don't rebuild mof files as the first step:

> "Rebuilding the repository or recompiling all of the .mof files as a first action when other steps should be taken first can cause damage to the system and/or to installed applications."

Answer (score 0):

Cannot convert value "\server1\root\default:stdregprov" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". **Error: "not found"**

This error is because it did not find the key that you are looking for. That's a basic case when key does not exist. Can you check if registry key exists?

As per the information provide, there is no issue with `WMI` here.

You can always use try and catch block to throw exception and move forward.